# Regex: How to match a part of the text within two characters e.g. quotes

Tags: regex, string

I need to match a text within a text that is surrounded by two characters, in this case ‘ and ’. So assume that the whole string is:

> Regarding the cat, I asked him ‘can you take care of my cat while I am away’ and he
>   said ‘yes’.

Now, if I use the following regex

```
(?<=‘)(.*?)(?=’)
```

It will match

> can you take care of my cat while I am away

and

> yes

What if I want to search for a *single character* e.g. "e" (matches in both quoted strings) or *word* e.g. "cat" within those two groups? How can I do that? I cannot figure out how to replace (.*?) in order to search for a substring/character within those special quotes.

Comment: Can you explain the example of `cat`. i'm not able to understand

Comment: @KeyurShah If I want to match the word cat, it should match the "cat" inside the substring surrounded by  ‘’, not the one outside it (see my updated example). So in other words, it will match one occurence of cat, not two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to replace the dot that is too permissive with a class that excludes the closing quote and the first character of your target:

```
(?<=‘)([^’e]*(e)[^’]*)(?=’)
```

or

```
(?<=‘)([^’c]*(?:(?:\Bc|c(?!at\b))[^’c]*)*\b(cat)\b[^’]*)(?=’)
```

Comment: Can you check what's wrong with this one [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5l8lwg/1)

Comment: @KeyurShah: in this case the situation is different since the opening and closing quotes are the same.

Comment: @KeyurShah: To catch all the cats between same single quotes the pattern is more complicated since you need to know which one is an opening quote and which one is a closing quote (using the `\G` anchors to ensure the contiguity between matches): https://regex101.com/r/H802eu/1

Comment: Yes, It too complicated to find opening and closing quote. For me i would prefer to use 2 regex to do this 1st to find string between quotes and other to find cat in that string. it would simpler. You should update your answer with that regex you just shared. Thanks